# Long string will split into lines when it reached maximum length in Java

Tags: java

```
String[] string = {"Terms of service are the legal agreements between a service provider and a person who wants to use that service.", "The person must agree to abide by the terms of service in order to use the offered service."};
```

Anyone knows how to make a string element in a string array above split into new lines when it reached the maximum length which is, let say 20.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So it's not like people here gonna solve it for you, You need to show what you have tried till now and what issues are you facing while doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Stream#flatMap` along with `String#split`.

```
int maxLen = 20;
String[] res = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(s -> 
     Arrays.stream(s.split("(?<=\\G.{" + maxLen + "})"))).toArray(String[]::new);
// Separate each element based on the maximum length 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```